# PowerBI Visual Tools - 400 Bad Request

Tags: powershell, powerbi

Could you help me out with the '400 Bad Request' error when installing the **powerbi-visuals-tools** in the PowerShell?

Actually I put

```
  npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools
```

and then get the error, as follows:

[image]

As I am under the corporate network I tried to change the VPN and proxy connections but got the same problem.

Comment: did you install NodeJS (at least version 4.0) first?

Comment: yes I did. Before trying to set the command I typed `node -v` to check the version and if it was installed. But unfortunately the error pesisted even after resintalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check whether the below steps were followed:
We don’t need any type of network.
Open Windows PowerShell -> by searching on the windows search bar
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1D6d.jpg

Now, to install power bi visualization tools. Type the below command in Windows PowerShell
npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqbXr.jpg

No network is required to install powerbi visuals tool. as we can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLl5h.jpg

As we can see without a network we can install power bi visualization tools
We have installed it successfully.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7xZr.jpg